# Wrong Error in Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My Visual Studio 2013 is going crazy , in view I get lot of Error for code Like this :

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type,  new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

And

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control" } )
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

But when i rebuilt project ,No error will be displayed.
And After a few seconds the Errors returns.
when i run project , every think alright.
But lately I used this code :

```
<div>
     <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"> @Html.ActionLink("go back to list", "Index", "ShowMembers",new {id = int.Parse(ViewData["AdminId"].ToString())},null) </i>
</div>

<li>
     @Html.ActionLink("setting", "Index", "AdminSetting", new { id = int.Parse(ViewData["AdminId"].ToString()) }, new { @class = "fa fa-gear fa-fw" })
</li>
```

And again, i get lot of error for above codes But this time when i run project and i go inside this page i get below error:

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1520: Method must have a return type

This below lines for action of controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = -1,int AdminId = -1)
    {
        if (Session["AdminId"] != null && Session["AdminName"] != null)
        {
            repository = new Repository();
            var member = repository.FindMemberById(id);

            return View(member);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminLogin");
        }
    }
```

This is my Source Error:

> Line 1294:            #line default
>
> Line 1295:            #line hidden
>
> Line 1296:BeginContext("~/Areas/Administrator/Views/ShowMembers/Edit.cshtml", 
>   6849, 47, true);
>
> Line 1297:
>
> Line 1298:WriteLiteral("\r\n                \r\n

how i solved this?

Comment: What method does it take you to if you click this error message? Does it have a return type?

Comment: you could probably avoid this by using roles or claims and use the `Authorise` attribute to check if the user is an admin or not. It looks to me that this is what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @Spluf , i use this method for all of my page , so its working right

Comment: is that the error you get every time? have you tried debugging to see which method throws that error? your controller looks fine, your razor as well...

Comment: I debugged, my controllers are fine

Comment: then I don't think you're showing the right code, something else is throwing your exception, debug, see what it is, and if you can't fix it post the right code here.

Comment: I delete temp file in temp asp.net folder but it's not working yet

Comment: if your exceptions are showing in the error list tab from visual studio just click on that exception and it will take you to the code that throws it (as @leigero said earlier).

Comment: @Spluf my Friend, it's not throws any exception. just this error in browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110293/discussion-between-spluf-and-komeil-shahmoradi).

Comment: running custom tool on your view could solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use two }} in below line :

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type,  new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" }})
```

correct is below line:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type,  new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```